# Why is my VGG16 not learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I've been following the series on [Keras Python Deep Learning](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrwRnXk_yCPtnqqo4_u2YGL) and, afaik, have produced the same code as used in the examples.

However, I cannot produce the same result.

````
# Imports


import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


# https://github.com/smileservices/keras_utils/blob/master/utils.py
# plots images with labels within jupyter notebook
def plots(ims, figsize=(12,6), rows=1, interp=False, titles=None):
    if type(ims[0]) is np.ndarray:
        ims = np.array(ims).astype(np.uint8)
        if (ims.shape[-1] != 3):
            ims = ims.transpose((0,2,3,1))
    f = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    cols = len(ims)//rows if len(ims) % 2 == 0 else len(ims)//rows + 1
    for i in range(len(ims)):
        sp = f.add_subplot(rows, cols, i+1)
        sp.axis('Off')
        if titles is not None:
            sp.set_title(titles[i], fontsize=16)
        plt.imshow(ims[i], interpolation=None if interp else 'none')

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.tight_layout()
```

# Setup

# https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data
# train_path = 'cats-and-dogs-demo/train' # 20
# valid_path = 'cats-and-dogs-demo/valid' # 8
# test_path = 'cats-and-dogs-demo/test'   # 5


# https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/
# 20
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10, shuffle=True
)

    Found 40 images belonging to 2 classes.

imgs, labels = next(train_batches)
plots(imgs, titles=labels)


# 8
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    valid_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=4, shuffle=True
)

    Found 16 images belonging to 2 classes.

valid_imgs, valid_labels = next(valid_batches)
plots(valid_imgs, titles=valid_labels)

# Build Fine-Tuned VGG16 Model
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()

# vgg16_model.summary()


model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(
    train_batches, steps_per_epoch=4, validation_data=valid_batches, validation_steps=4, epochs=5, verbose=1
)

    Epoch 1/5
    4/4 [==============================] - 16s 4s/step - loss: 2.0606 - acc: 0.3500 - val_loss: 1.5746 - val_acc: 0.3125
    Epoch 2/5
    4/4 [==============================] - 15s 4s/step - loss: 1.7596 - acc: 0.3500 - val_loss: 1.8654 - val_acc: 0.3125
    Epoch 3/5
    4/4 [==============================] - 16s 4s/step - loss: 1.3629 - acc: 0.4000 - val_loss: 1.4927 - val_acc: 0.5625
    Epoch 4/5
    4/4 [==============================] - 19s 5s/step - loss: 0.8355 - acc: 0.5750 - val_loss: 1.0068 - val_acc: 0.5000
    Epoch 5/5
    4/4 [==============================] - 19s 5s/step - loss: 0.4258 - acc: 0.7750 - val_loss: 0.9116 - val_acc: 0.6875

# 5
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    test_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=5, shuffle=False
)

    Found 10 images belonging to 2 classes.

test_imgs, test_labels = next(test_batches)
test_labels = test_labels[:,0]
test_labels

    array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)

predictions = model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=1, verbose=0)
cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels, np.round(predictions[:,0]))
cm_plot_labels = ['cat','dog']
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, cm_plot_labels, title='Confusion Matrix')

    Confusion matrix, without normalization
    true cat [[0 0]
         dog  [3 2]]
               c d
               a o
               t g
               Predicted

test_imgs, test_labels = next(test_batches)
test_labels = test_labels[:,0]
test_labels

    array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)

# Predict using Fine-Tuned VGG16 Model
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=1, verbose=0)
cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels, np.round(predictions[:,0]))
cm_plot_labels = ['cat','dog']
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, cm_plot_labels, title='Confusion Matrix')

    Confusion matrix, without normalization
    True cat [[1 4]
         dog  [0 0]]
               c d
               a o
               t g
               Predicted
````

Comment: why do you say it's not learning ?

Comment: I've added some labels. Perhaps it's learning something, but it can't produce anything close to the results in the video. AFAIK I'm using the same images, in the same folders, with the same code. When I run it, it cannot categorise the cat and dog images properly. 2 out of 5 for cat images and 1 out of 5 for dog images.

Comment: if you look at the epoches print, it is learning. You just don't let it train enough. I don't see the video, maybe they train for a bit longer, or maybe they are lucky (that can happen).
your accuracy on epoch 5 is 77.5% and not even 70% on the validation set, thus it is not crazy to have your results.

Comment: Should I increase the epochs or something else?

Comment: yes, your accuracy increases at each epoch, don't seems to be stuck, so let it trains a bit more ! you should try t have at least a 90% accuracy, even better if it's on the validation set. then test it and see. If the results are not better, you can try to ask yourself about your network ! And maybe try to use more image, for both datasets, it would be better for statistics (recognize 4 images out of 5 could be purely luck, whereas recognize 19 images out of 20 is less unlikcy luck)

Comment: This is the run with 15 epochs: https://github.com/HoraceBury/vgg16/blob/master/.ipynb_checkpoints/cats-and-dogs_20-8-5_VGG16-checkpoint.ipynb

Comment: As you can see, the accuracy hits 1.0000 - so why can it not tell the difference? Regardless of the text labels, the predicted labels are just mostly wrong. Is it because 'model.predict_generator' calls 'next(test_batches)' internally?

Comment: Maybe you use different labels when you test or their format is different.

Comment: Should the labels be reversed at some point? The folders are 'cat' and 'dog', obviously in that order. Should the labels I use be 'dog' then 'cat' at some point?